# Reverse engineering an elliptic curve from its modular form?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Does there exist an algorithm or something of the sort to reverse-engineer a curve from its modular form (weight two eigenform with complex coefficients)? I am aware that sometimes there isn’t a unique elliptic curve paired with a given modular form, but is there way to get just one?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. I think this can be done by computing the period lattice, see chapter 2 here http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgaj/book/fulltext/index.html

Comment: I wouldn't call it "reverse engineering" as this is much older than the way to associate a modular form to the elliptic curve. For instance the [Antwerp IV tables](https://wstein.org/Tables/antwerp/index.html) did this systematically, then Cremona's tables (Will's link above) now on [lmfdb](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/) extended it.